# running external C# file in a program

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, reflection

Does the .NET framework have any classes which allow you to run (compile, interpret or whatever) an external script file containing C# code?

For instance, if I have a file `Hello.cs` containing this:

```
class Hello
//This program displays Hello World
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

how can i load the code above, from within a winform, app and execute it?

I'm interested in the load/execute logic; the program could be anything, from a console app to another winform app.

Does Reflection allow this?

Comment: Check out the ScriptEngine in Roslyn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/roslyn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the following article: [C#: Writing extendable applications using on-the-fly compilation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2006/02/09/528416.aspx).

Comment: just the title tells a lot - that's exaclty what i'm lookng for !! on the fly baby :) thanks dude

Answer (score 2):

> Does the .NET framework have any classes which allow you to run
>   (compile, interpret or whatever) an external script file containing C#
>   code?

Yes, you can use the [CodeDomProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.aspx) class.

> how can i load the code above, from within a winform, app and execute
>   it?

Well,after compile the C# code using the above class,you can use the [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) class and pass it as argument of [`Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) method from [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class and then read the [`StandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) stream,store it on a string and show as you want,`Console.Write()`, `MessageBox.Show()` etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would check the Roslyn APIs. You can do what ever you want as long as you provide valid C# o VB.NET code.